# Passing a variable into an object variable

Tags: javascript

Say I have:

```
var dogColour = "black"
var dogSize = "Medium"

dogStats = {"COLOUR": dogColour, "DOGSIZE": dogSize};
```

would this output as I require it? eg:

```
dogStats = {"COLOUR": black, "DOGSIZE": Medium};
```

When I view source it simply shows `dogStats = {"COLOUR": dogColour, "DOGSIZE": dogSize};` rather than with the variable output.

Comment: It will output as you need it.

Comment: What else will `viewsource` show. It will show your source as is. But your output will have the values as replaced by your variables unless you have them wrapped in quotes in your original code.

Comment: can you produce a fiddle ?

Comment: @peter - in firefox/chrome, type in your debugger console: dogStats - that will give you the value of that object. The source code is the rendered of the page, you won't see the dynamic setting of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Of course when you view the source it will show you `dogStats = {"COLOUR": dogColour, "DOGSIZE": dogSize};`, after all, that is your source.

If you `alert(dogStats.COLOUR);` then it'll alert you with, "black"

I'm not sure what your question is, but perhaps this will help guide you towards what you're after.